# Obliteração de tags! A tag web-api-2 e seu sinônimo asp.net-web-api2 não deveriam existir!

Tags: debate

Recentemente notei uma coisa no site, existe uma tag chamada [web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api-2) que estava sendo utilizada por umas 40 perguntas para se referir, na maioria dos casos, à conceitos pertinentes às tags [web-api](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api) (no conceito de Web API de acordo com [esse artigo do Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API)), [asp.net-web-api](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) e [asp.net-web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api-2).

Então aqui seguem alguns outros motivos pelos quais a tag [web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api-2) deveria ser obliterada do site:

- A Microsoft possui um framework com o nome de ASP.NET Web API, e esse é o nome desse framework, não é WebAPI, Web API, WebApi2, ou qualquer que seja o outro nome que caiu na boca do povo;
- O ASP.NET Web API está atualmente na versão 2 e por esse motivo, aparentemente, acabaram criando a tag [web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api-2) e a utilizando com esse intuito;
- Se for realmente necessário se referir especificamente à versão 2 do framework utilize a tag [asp.net-web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api-2) (e aqui é que surge outro problema).

Por qual motivo criaram a [asp.net-web-api2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api2) como sinônimo da tag [web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api-2)?!

Gente... quando forem criar uma tag para uma versão específica de um framework por exemplo, e caso esse framework já tenha uma tag própria, sigam o seguinte padrão:

```
[tag-do-framework]-[versão]
```

Por exemplo, num universo hipotético existe um framework chamado Cachorrinho.js, Cachorrinho.js já possui uma tag no site, [cachorrinho.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cachorrinho.js), mas foi lançada a versão 2 desse framework e o usuário Foo está com um problema específico por causa dessa nova versão, usuário Foo então resolve fazer uma pergunta no SOpt e adiciona as seguintes tags à sua pergunta, [cachorrinho.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cachorrinho.js) e [cachorrinho.js-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cachorrinho.js-2). Foo é um usuário esperto, ele sabe utilizar as tags corretamente, seja com Foo.

E esse é o motivo pelo qual o [asp.net-web-api2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api2), que está como sinônimo da tag [web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api-2), deveria ser obliterado também.

P.S.: Já editei as perguntas que utilizavam a tag [web-api-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api-2) e a substituí por outras mais adequadas.

Comment: Não entendi nada porque não manjo dos paranaue, mas leve meu +1 pelo "obliteração". :)

Comment: Agora entendi o motivo de existir várias perguntas sobre isto na primeira página hoje a tarde.

Comment: @renan hahaha foram minhas edições em massa, 40 edições feitas manualmente... uma a uma... devia ter usado a API do Stack Exchange e montado um script para fazer isso... (TT-TT)

Comment: Então está resolvido?

Comment: @bfavaretto não, meu post foi totalmente ignorado, e a tag ainda existe xD